# Get the duration of video file with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js for uploading contents.

I have been searching a few hours for a way to get the duration of video file like other properties are accessible in this library like "Size , width, height and name) however I have not found anything.

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use external library, some extension/application on your server. For example ffprobe. Its impossible to check video duration with javascript.

If you use only standard html5 formats like mp4, you can use callback:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
  init: function () {
    this.on("complete", function (file) {
      if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        console.log(file); // here you can check where is filename etc.
        $('<video>').attr('src', value); // create video tag, and check it
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I didn't use Dropzone.js and used like as normal simple input File type wouldn't I be able to get the duration? like :  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp

Comment: with html5 you can check only few formats. If you dont need support for older browsers and you accept only mp4 and ogg it will be good solution. You can dynamically use some callback with dropzone to create specific tags and get values

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more for me with "dynamically use some callback with dropzone to create specific tags and get values" ?

Comment: I added callback example in my answer. You know how to create <video> element right?